# pdfbox does not respect white space

Tags: whitespace, pdfbox

Hi I am trying to create a PDF with pdfbox 2.0

I need to print a simple loan amortization table  like these

```
|   18 |     933.80 |     807.49 |     126.31 |   6,082.49 | 2017-04-12 |
|   19 |     933.80 |     822.29 |     111.51 |   5,260.20 | 2017-05-12 |
|   20 |     933.80 |     837.36 |      96.43 |   4,422.83 | 2017-06-12 |
|   21 |     933.80 |     852.72 |      81.08 |   3,570.11 | 2017-07-12 |
```

Exampple code:

```
cos.beginText();
    cos.setFont(fontPlain, 12);
    cos.newLineAtOffset(98, rect.getHeight() - spaceBetweenLines * (++line));
    cos.showText("|   24 |     933.80 |     900.48 |      33.32 |     916.99 | 2017-10-12 |");
    cos.endText();
    cos.beginText();
    cos.setFont(fontPlain, 12);
    cos.newLineAtOffset(98, rect.getHeight() - spaceBetweenLines * (++line));
    cos.showText("|   25 |     933.80 |     916.99 |      16.81 |       0.00 | 2017-11-12 |");
    cos.endText();
```

But then the resulting pdf file remove some white-spaces.

[image: Loan PDF IMAGE]

I don´t know to fix these

Answer (score 2):

That is because the space character has a different width than the digits. As you can see from the image it starts being off as soon as the number of digits differ in a column.

You can get the width for a string with `PDFont.getStringWidth(String text)`(don't include the spaces) and move the position within a line using `newLineAtOffset`which you are already doing

Comment: Alternatively the OP may switch to a truly monospaced font.

Comment: OP = original poster, the one who asked, you.